# Tela login SQLITE

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou tentando realizar a verificação de existência do usuário e do login ao realizar o acesso no sistema. 
Estou utilizando os seguintes códigos:

```
public int login(String username,String password)
    {
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{username, password};
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            Cursor c = null;
            c = db.rawQuery("select * from usuarios where login=? and senha=?", selectionArgs);
            c.moveToFirst();
            i = c.getCount();
            c.close();
            System.out.println("AQUIII " + i);
            return i;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

E a chamada dessa função:

```
if (bd.login(usuario.toString(),senha.toString()) == 0 ){

                        usuario.setError("");
                        senha.setError("");

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Senha ou usuário não existente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();

                    }
```

Mas ele não esta realizando a ação conforme o esperado. Qualquer dado que eu informo como usuario e senha ele dá que não existe.

Comment: Está mostrando algum erro no seu logcat?

Comment: @acklay não não. O retorno de do método login é sempre 0

Comment: Mas já verificou se de fato o usuário está cadastrado!?

Comment: @acklay quando eu dou um print na list que possui os usuários cadastrado o mesmo está la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como está usando um editText terás q fazer essa troca:

de:

```
if (bd.login(usuario.toString(),senha.toString()) == 0 ){
```

para

```
if (bd.login(usuario.getText().toString(),senha.getText().toString()) == 0){
```